# Bitbucket login authentication failed in terminal

Tags: bitbucket

Recently formatted my machine, when try to clone the project repositories again with my main bitbucket credentials, faced these errors..

```
remote: Login failed due to incorrect login credentials or method.
remote: If you are unsure of which login details or login method to use, visit:
remote: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/log-into-or-connect-to-bitbucket-cloud/
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/xxxxxxx/repository.git/'
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed.

Hadn't created an App Password at `Account > Personal settings > App password`

Create new password for your git operations. Once create new password, use that password, for git actions in terminal, it works.